# Hacker Rank Question SQL Advanced Mysql query Incorrect syntax (only full group by mode)

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Question:

> Julia conducted a 15 days of learning SQL contest. The start date of the contest was March 01, 2016 and the end date was March 15, 2016.
>
> Write a query to print total number of unique hackers who made at least submission each day (starting on the first day of the contest), and find the `hacker_id` and name of the hacker who made maximum number of submissions each day. If more than one such hacker has a maximum number of submissions, print the lowest `hacker_id`. The query should print this information for each day of the contest, sorted by the date.
>
> **Input Format**
> The following tables hold contest data:
>
> - `Hackers`: The `hacker_id` is the id of the hacker, and `name` is the name of the hacker.
> - `Submissions`: The `submission_date` is the date of the submission, `submission_id` is the id of the submission, `hacker_id` is the id of the hacker who made the submission, and `score` is the score of the submission.
>
> **Sample Input**
> For the following sample input, assume that the end date of the contest was March 06, 2016.
>
> [Hackers Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDSl9.png)
> [Submissions Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crpb3.png)
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 2016-03-01 4 20703 Angela
> 2016-03-02 2 79722 Michael
> 2016-03-03 2 20703 Angela
> 2016-03-04 2 20703 Angela
> 2016-03-05 1 36396 Frank
> 2016-03-06 1 20703 Angela
> ```

My query so far is following:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  @s := submission_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT hacker_id),
  @h := (SELECT hacker_id
         FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                 hacker_id,
                 @ch := COUNT(hacker_id)
               FROM Submissions
               WHERE submission_date=@s
               ORDER BY @ch
               GROUP BY hacker_id DESC) x
         LIMIT 1),
  @n:=(SELECT name FROM Hackers WHERE hacker_id=@h)
FROM
  Submissions
WHERE 1;
```

Well this query fails 'SQL sytax error'{MYSQL}, however without `GROUP BY` this query is rejected as only-full-group-by mode is activated.

Error Message is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY hacker_id DESC) x LIMIT 1),@n:=(SELECT name FROM Hackers WHERE hacker_i' at line 1

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: *Sample Input* Provide sample input which results in shown sample output as complete CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the column name after WHERE.

Try this:

```
SELECT <your query> FROM Submissions WHERE <column name> = 1;
```

I think this will be helpful for you.